# Tornado coroutine yield from another coroutine incrementally

Tags: tornado, coroutine

I wanted to refactor a part of my Tornado application and so I have created a special function for returning phone numbers:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get_phones(self, listname):
    phones = []
    logging.info("fetching phones")
    cursor = self._mongo.contacts.aggregate(self.get_query(
        subscription_filter={
            "$ne": [{"$ifNull": ["$$subscription.events.{listname}", None]}, None]
        },
        handler_filter={
            "handler.meta.is_active": True,
            "handler.meta.type": "phone"
        }
    ))
    try:
        while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
            contact = cursor.next_object()
            logging.info(contact)
            try:
                phones += [handler['subject'] for handler in contact['handlers']]
                if len(phones) > 50:
                    yield phones
                    phones = []
            except Exception:
                self._logger.warning("Could not get phone no")
    except Exception:
        phones = []
        logging.warning("Could not fetch contacts")

    if len(phones) > 0:
        yield phones
```

What I wanted to achieve with this is asynchronously fetch batches of up to 50 contacts from my DB and return them to the calling coroutine.

This is my calling coroutine:

```
@gen.coroutine
def on_heartbeat_status_update(self, status):
    phonegen = self.get_phones("ews:admin")
    logging.info(phonegen)
    while True:
        phones = yield phonegen
        logging.info(phones)
        if phones is None:
            break
        logging.info(len(phones))
```

It's not working. "phones" is always None. Can someone suggest the proper way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use Python 3.6 native coroutines for this to work. This was the first version of Python that supported both `yield` and `await` in the same function. Without this, it is impossible for the system to distinguish between using `yield` for a coroutine and yielding a result as a generator.

Replace `@gen.coroutine def` with `async def` and use `await cursor.fetch_next` and `yield phones` in `get_phones`. Then you can use `async for phones in self.get_phones(...)` in `on_heartbeat_status_update`.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Your suggestion did the trick. There is one more thing that I need to figure out though. What if the get_phones() function yields a lot of stuff? How can I make sure in the caller function that other stuff that is scheduled on the ioloop gets a chance to run ?

Comment: Doing this:
          async for phoneslist in self.get_phones("ews:admin"):
              self.send_sms(sms, phoneslist)
              await tornado.gen.sleep(0)
does not seem to work. If i yield in a while True inside the get_phones function then nothing else on the IOloop gets a chance to run.

Comment: `await sleep(0)` should allow other stuff to run. I'm not sure what might be happening here.

Comment: According to my tests await sleep(0.01) does allow other stuff to happen but just doing await sleep(0) does not according to my observations. Might be something else that I am doing wrong. I will continue digging around.